# Can Postfix prevent duplicate in RCPT TO address?

Tags: postfix

My server running opends for LDAP and postfix dovecot procmail delivery

My /etc/aliases contain the group of email address, for example :

all : a@mydomain.com, b@mydomain.com, c@mydomain.com.....

manager: a@mydomain.com, d@mydomain.com

If someone send messages to all@mydomain.com, manager@mydomain.com, the user a@mydomain.com will recieve 2 messages

I have many groups which user a@mydomain.com belong to

Is there a way for user a@mydomain.com can recieve only 1 messages!

Thank folks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `enable_original_recipient = no`.

From `postconf(5)`:

> enable_original_recipient (default: yes)
>
> > Enable support for the X-Original-To message header. This header is needed for multi-recipient mailboxes.
> >
> > When this parameter is set to yes, the cleanup(8) daemon performs duplicate elimination on distinct pairs of (original recipient, rewritten recipient), and generates non-empty original recipient queue file records.
> >
> > When this parameter is set to no, the cleanup(8) daemon performs duplicate elimination on the rewritten recipient address only, and generates empty original recipient queue file records.
> >
> > This feature is available in Postfix 2.1 and later. With Postfix version 2.0, support for the X-Original-To message header is always turned on. Postfix versions before 2.0 have no support for the X-Original-To message header.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but you can also see if something similar to this would work:

```
all : manager, b@mydomain.com, c@mydomain.com.....

manager: a@mydomain.com, d@mydomain.com
```